# Showing UIImageView after finished loading

Tags: swift, uiimageview

Currently I have a collection view of thumbnail images, Upon pressing that thumbnail image cell then it should call a function that would retrieve the Image data via API and shows the full image via the hidden ImageView.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            dataManager.downloadAttachment(id: attachments[indexPath.row].attachmentID)
            if dataManager.dataHolder != nil {
                attachmentImage.image = UIImage.init(data: dataManager.dataHolder!)
                attachmentImage.isHidden = false
            }
            print(attachments[indexPath.row].attachmentID)
        }
```

and

```
func downloadAttachment(id:Int) {
    let finalUrl = "\(urlAttachment)\(id)/data"
    if let url = URL(string: finalUrl){
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: header)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            print("Attachment Downloaded")
            self.dataHolder = data
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

The obvious issue with this is that the image wouldn't show on the first attempt since it would still be retrieving the image and the dataHolder would still be **nil**, But if I tap on the cell twice then the image will be shown correctly.

Is there a simple way to maybe just tap once and make it shows a place holder until finished downloading and update the place holder with an actual image accordingly? Or any other proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closures to achieve what you asked for. The updated code looks like this.

```
func downloadAttachment(id:Int,completionHandler completion: @escaping ((Data)->Void)) {
let finalUrl = "\(urlAttachment)\(id)/data"
if let url = URL(string: finalUrl){
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue(apiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: header)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        print("Attachment Downloaded")
        self.dataHolder = data
        completion()
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

Now in collectionViewDidSelectItemAt make this changes

```
func collectionView (_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      dataManager.downloadAttachment(id: attachments[indexPath.row].attachmentID,completionHandler: { data in
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath),
                      let data = dataManager.dataHolder,
                      let image = UIImage.init(data: data){
            attachmentImage.image = image
            attachmentImage.isHidden = false
            }
     })
 }
```

Comment: Thanks it’s working now. Needed to add @escaping though.

Comment: Thank you. Forgot mentioning it. Updated the answer.